# How can I change the column name from datagridview with access database

Tags: vb.net

[image: I want to change this one]

or how can I populate the rows only from my datagridview since I want to assign a columnheader name on my datagridview instead of filling the database with all my data. I want to adjust the column height/width and such of each column. Thank you

Comment: ps, if those are real email addreses in the image, a bit of obscurity would go a long way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why you put an image, but you should perhaps try to avoid it for future questions; people tend to prefer seeing code as text they can copypaste

You have your DGV set to autogenerate columns so it makes columns with a HeaderText that is the same name as the column. Just change the column HeaderText *after the columns have been bound* (binding happens when you set the DataSource property):

For example you can look the DGV column up by the datatable column it is bound to:

```
yourDataGridView.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)().First(Function(c) c.DataPropertyName = "ip").HeaderText = "IP"
```

Bound columns don't have a name, only an index position, so if you want to find them by name you'll have to look through the columncollection searching for eg where the column's DataPropertyName is "ip", which is what the LINQ above does. It's a bit awkward as a syntax because a DataGridViewColumnCollection doesn't do LINQ without being cast. It might be simpler to put all your mappings into a dictionary and use a loop:

```
Dim d = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
  {{"ip", "IP"}, {"aws", "AmazonWebServices"}, ... }
For Each dgvc as DataGridViewColumn in d
  If d.ContainsKey dgvc.DataPropertyName Then d.HeaderText = d(dgvc.DataPropertyName)
Next dgvc
```

---

If you know "ip" column will always be first you can more simply:

```
yourDataGridView.Columns(0).HeaderText = "IP"
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve my problem. Always a lifesaver. By the way, wanted to know how you edit my post, instead of displaying the image as image link, you make the image as viewable. (just a minor thing though) :D

Comment: When you add an image, SO puts like `[enter image description here][1]` - put a `!` before it, so it's like `![enter...`. (Actually, when I add an image, I usually use snipping tool to take a screen shot, then just press ctrl-c, come to so, press ctrl-v and it adds the ! for me)

Comment: Note that, if you create the columns in the designer, you get to control every aspect of their appearance. Just set the `DataPropertyName` to specify what property/column of the data source to bind to.

Comment: Actually "here's one I made earlier" - https://youtu.be/zrtjZlTYLQA - at around 4:39 I'm in the "datagridview columns editor" panel, and the HeaderText property is clearly visible - that's where you'd edit it if you were taking a visual design approach, but it might be worth watching the entire video to that point (at least, if not to the end) because what goes before demonstrates some of the ways VS can make your "want to get data out of an access db and show it on a form" life easier